# Child dont detect parent changes Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Hi i have a question how it realy work. I have a 2 components parent and child (i show only a piece of code because its my work project).

So the parent component piece of template :

```
<product-empty [showHistoryMonth]="showHistoryMonth" [showHistoryAvg]="showHistoryAvg"
           [SP_L_FCSQData]='SP_L_FCSQData'
           [allHistoryAvgNames]="allHistoryAvgNames" [salesPlanId]="salesPlanId" [allHistoryChannels]="allHistoryChannels" [airingsNames]="airingsNames"
           [allForecastMonthChannels]="allForecastMonthChannels" [forecastShows]="displayArry"
           [allProductSummary]="allProductSummary"  ></product-empty>
```

and function which is important in this case :

```
private displayArry: string[] = [];

getForecastDisplay(emit: any) {
        if (emit.show) {
            var index = this.displayArry.indexOf(emit.id);
            if (index === -1) {
                this.displayArry.push(emit.id);
            } else { }
        } else {
            var index = this.displayArry.indexOf(emit.id);
            this.displayArry.splice(index, 1);
        }
        this.forecastShows = emit;
        console.log('forecast show', this.displayArry);
    }
```

And the child component piece :

```
export class FlexProductEmptyComponent implements DoCheck, OnInit, OnChanges {
    ...
    @Input() showHistoryMonth: boolean = false;
    @Input() showHistoryAvg: boolean = false;
    @Input() forecastShows: any;
    ...
```

So the question is how data is passing beetwen parent and child. Right now i try to detect a parent changes in child.
EDIT : The getForecastDisplay function is called when other component emit data and update displayArry. So like i think when displayArry variable is changed is passed again to all children which are binded to parent.

I mean i try to catch that moment when parent data changed and pass it to child.
I used a setter and when i set a console log on it it only loggs on init.
I used a OnChanges with simple change and its logged only on startup of component;
But data when are changed is passed to child component (i know it because i set a console log in doCheck and its show a correct value).

So the main question is how i can catch that moment when the parent component pass changed data to child ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to enable communications between parent and children components, the most obvious one is through [input and output properties](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs), or through services. Observable is another option. Here's [an example with BehaviorSubject(a special kind of Observable)](https://plnkr.co/edit/DaDdt7HlJ3l6jkroUxxy?p=preview). The steps are as following:

- 'new' a BehaviorSubject in parent, let's name it `someRxx`.
- pass the BehaviorSubject to child using input property, like `<my-child [nameRxx]="someRxx"></my-child>`.
- in child template, use async pipe, like `<h2>Hello {{nameRxx | async}}</h2>`; or in child componet, you do `nameRxx.subscribe(doSomething)` (don't foget to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy)
- in parent component or its template, do `someRxx.next(value)`, child will receive the value whenever you do `.next`.

Enjoy.

Comment: I will try it and give feedback :)